# How to restore sound after using Windows Remote Connection?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, remote-desktop

I have used the remote connection from windows to connect a windows to another (both win 7) and after I logged off, there is no sound at all on the remote pc.

Before connecting the first time, I didn't configure the sound options so it brought the sound to the connecting pc. After that, i have changed the sound to stay on the remote pc and logged in/off but the remote pc remained with no sound.

I did try to disconnect the session with tscon (tscon.exe 1 /dest:console) but it remained the same...

The sound options on the pc are all as they should and the drivers seem ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: The sound usually returns to the PC. Have you tried reopening the application that play the sounds?

Comment: Yes, i have spotify and it is not doing sound... Not even the system plays sounds...

Comment: In the Sound control panel, do you see any devices?

Comment: Yes, and default device is correct and appears to be working because the "test" works (visually) but it has no sound.

Comment: And through the command "qwinsta" i only see 2 connections: 
Name:Services Username:NO d:0 State:Disk
Name:Console Username:YES Id:1 State:Active
If i disconnect the session id 1, it ends the current (local) session.
I have disabled remote access to the pc, hoping that would help... Please, any ideas?

Comment: Please don't add SOLVED to the title, instead please click "answer your question" at the bottom of the page, and then click the tick next to your answer to show that that is how you solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a system restore and that solved it. Thanks for the help!